# Python __init__/General Function Inline Equals In Argument(s):

Tags: python, oop

I am tasked with converting some Python code to Java. I have some experience with Python, but am unfamiliar with some of its features.

I see an `__init__` method which I understand is essentially a constructor.

I expect to see arguments like this:

`def __init__(self,derp1, derp2, derp3):`

But in one part of the code, I see:

`def __init__(self,derp1=0, derp2=0, derp3=0):`

Now, to me, it looks like this is some sort of conditional constructor, used specifically when (self,0,0,0) has been passed. This shouldn't be the case, because there is no alternative constructor.

It also shouldn't be an inline assignment, as that just doesn't make sense.

I've tried Googling to figure out what this means, but I'm not having much luck.

I appreciate any help you can offer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're [Default Argument Values](http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/defaultArgs.html).

I think Java doesn't support it.

Comment: A wonderfully quick answer. I can not accept this for another eleven minutes due to StackOverflow's limits, but I will do so when I may. I really appreciate this.

Answer (score 3):

Those are default parameters.  You could initialize a class instance like `my_class(1, 2, 3)` and it would set derp1 to 1, derp2 to 2 and derp3 to 3.  Because defaults are provided, you could also call it like `my_class(5)` and it would set derp1 to 5, derp2 to 0 and derp3 to 0.

Keep in mind that the derp variables are local to the `__init__` function so you need to assign them to some class variable if you want to hold onto them. For example, in `__init__`, you could save off the derp1 value by doing `self.derpaderp = derp1` and then refer to that value as `self.derpaderp` elsewhere in your class.

Comment: I understand it already from the link @CeramicPot gave, but definitely an upvote from me for the explanation, anyway. I knew using `derp` as part of a variable name would end up making me laugh while reading someone's answer, and as soon as I read `derpaderp`, that point was proved correct.

Comment: Glad to help.  Took me a bit longer to type up my answer apparently as I started typing 15 seconds after you asked :)  Good luck with your conversion efforts.

Comment: Thanks for the good luck. This was the only line holding me back, so I'm done!